# Восстановить файлы и каталоги после rm -r

Tags: debian

Как восстановить удалённые файлы и каталоги в дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux*?

Comment: Вам помогут программы для восстановления удаленных файлов extundelete, ext4magic, etc..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

программы для восстановления (из одноимённых пакетов): *testdisk*, *extundelete* (только для файловых систем *ext*), *foremost*, *scalpel*.

возможно, некоторые из них и позволяют работать с примонтированными файловыми системами, но безопаснее, конечно, этого не делать. и восстанавливать удалённые файлы безопаснее в другую файловую систему (примонтированную).

т.е., если удалённые файлы находились, например, в корневой файловой системе, то проще всего воспользоваться каким-нибудь *live-cd/dvd/usb* (к примеру, [systemrescuecd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/)), загрузившись с него.

инструкции по использованию перечисленных программ можно почитать, например, здесь: [http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/восстановление_данных](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)