# Как вернуть удаленные файлы в linux?

Tags: linux

Удалил несколько важных для меня файлов с расширением ".py". Как мне восстановить их при помощи программы "scalpel"?. Какую именно строчку мне нужно раскомментировать в конфиге данной программы?

Comment: Возможно вам, [Это поможет?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/247421/) ...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: здесь более специфичный вопрос: о том как сконфигрурировать scalpel, чтобы он `*.py` -файлы восстанавливал.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/526038/181472

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего для пайтона нет нужной строки в конфиг файле. 
Соответственно нужно создать свой шаблон:

```
Type    | Case sensitive    | Size range    | Header    | Footer    | Search option
py      | y                 | 100000000     | ???       | ???       | REVERCE
```

Я не знаю, есть ли какое-то обязательное начало у файла, как, например, в пхп `<?php и конец как ?>` (Header & Footer соответственно). Сайз ренж - любой (размер файла в байтах, фактически), можно в варианте ОТ:ДО

Вообще почитайте man scalpel, он на многое может открыть глаза.

UPD: Статью нашел вот: https://habrahabr.ru/post/247421/

Comment: И да, я, конечно, понимаю, что это ничего не изменит на данный момент - но в будущем попробуйте использовать любые способы бекапа. А лучше сделать git-repos (можно прям у себя на компе), и использовать его как систему контроля версий. Заодно и восстановить можно, в случае чего. А еще это полезная практика для разработчика любого уровня.

Comment: Не удалось востоновить файлы.

Comment: Добавил в шаблон ваши строки и в  "Header" написал "#!/usr/bin/python3.4". Программа сканировала мой "/dev/sdb6"(/home) около одного часа и затем остановилась без всяких сообщений. ..... Всё, больше не буду возвращаться к этой теме чтоб не травмировать свою психику...... >А лучше сделать git-repos . Спасибо за совет, буду пользоваться.

Comment: @MikeRu ну, из того, что я прочитал про скальпель пока искал, есть типы файлов, которые он восстановить не может. Ну или нужно пытаться восстановить их как обычный текст. Если Вы добавляли мою строку с вопросами - то оно и не могло ничего найти. Фактически если сделать $ cat <filename>  первые три символа должны попадать под header (а это ???) а последние три под footer (а в моем примере это опять таки ???). Тогда уже лучше использовать регулярное выражение обозначающее любые символы.